# Correct inline assembly code for sys_uname

Tags: c, x86, freebsd, inline-assembly, i386

I have written inline assembly code for the system call sys_uname, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscalls.h>
#include <string.h>

struct utsname stroj;
__asm__ volatile("pushl $0;"
              "pushl %%ebx;"
              "pushl $0;"
              "int $0x80;"
              :
              : "a" (SYS_uname), "b" (&stroj)
              );

//uname(&stroj); -> when I do this it works, but again, I want to use inline assembly
write(1, stroj.nodename, strlen(stroj.nodename)); // 1 = stdout
```

Is there some glaring problem that I am not addressing? This write prints out nothing, literally "".

Comment: Passing $0 twice might be wrong. Maybe one of them should be $1.

Comment: Edited, should be compilable. I also tried replacing one $0 with $1, no change in output.

Comment: I am on Unix, Intel 386, FreeBSD. One of those should be the answer to your question I hope

Comment: Is this for OS X?  Why are you pushing zeros on the stack?  Ok yeah, i386 FreeBSD does pass syscall args on the user-space stack.  Also, you forgot a `"memory"` clobber or memory output operand, so the compiler will assume that `stroj` is still unmodified and that it can compute `strlen` at compile time.  Did you try using `strace` or similar tool to trace system calls?

Comment: I have no experience using strace, this is my first attempt at inline assembly. I will add memory clobber.

Comment: Oh, you forgot to undo the `push`es after `int $0x80` returns.  So probably you broke the compiler's access to the stack.  Use your debugger's disassembly view, not source view, to see the interaction between inline-asm and compiler-generated asm.  (And use `strace` or `truss` or whatever FreeBSD has to see the system calls your process makes; usually a really easy way to spot mistakes in passing args.)

Comment: Is there a quick fix to this? Other than strace and so on.

Comment: @MichaelKročka: `strace` *is* quick.  Just `strace ./a.out` and right away you see what system calls your program made.  It's fantastic for debugging stuff like this, and would show you what system call libc `uname` made vs. whatever happened with your inline asm.  `strace` or equivalent tracing tool is an essential debugging tool for low level systems programming, and super helpful in general as a sysadmin (e.g. "what files does this program even look for"; it can help you find a config file you didn't know about, and solve path config problems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes there is a reason why you wish to use system calls directly rather than through *C* library functions.

A version of the inline assembly that would be correct could look like:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* SYS_uname has the value 164 */
/* #define SYS_uname 164 */

#define SYS_uname SYS_freebsd4_uname

int main()
{
    u_int syscallnum = SYS_uname;
    struct utsname stroj;

    asm("push %[stroj]\n\t"
        "push %%eax\n\t"        /* Required dummy value for int 0x80 */
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        "add $8, %%esp"         /* 2*4 bytes removed from stack */
        : "+a"(syscallnum)      /* error code also returned in syscallnum */
        : [stroj]"r"(&stroj)
        : "memory");

    write(1, stroj.nodename, strlen(stroj.nodename));
    return 0;
}
```

With [FreeBSD 32-bit system calls](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html) the parameters are pushed on the stack in reverse order. A dummy value (any value) has to be pushed on the stack before issuing `int $0x80`. You need to adjust the stack pointer *ESP* after the system call. Any registers that may change need to be dealt with as well. `int $0x80` will return an error code in *EAX*. The code above returns that value back in the `syscallnum` variable. If you modify a register in inline assembly and don't let GCC know it can cause undefined behaviour that is often hard to hunt down.

If you pass addresses via registers you will need to add memory operands (even if they are dummies) to specify that the data at the pointer in the registers is being read and/or written to. Alternatively you can specify the `memory` clobber which may be easier to understand although is a more brute force approach.

GCC's inline assembly is powerful but difficult to get right and can cause unexpected behaviour if you get it wrong. You should only use inline assembly as a [last resort](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm). FreeBSD has a [`syscall` function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syscall&sektion=2&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) that can be used to call most system calls.

You could have written the inline assembly above as:

```
asm(
    "push %[stroj]\n\t"
    "push %%eax\n\t"        /* Required dummy value for int 0x80 */
    "int $0x80\n\t"
    "add $8, %%esp"         /* 2*4 bytes removed from stack */
    : "+a"(syscallnum),     /* error code also returned in syscallnum */
      "=m"(stroj)
    : [stroj]"r"(&stroj));
```

---

### FreeBSD 2+ doesn't support obsolete SYS_uname

If you try to run the code above you will discover it doesn't return anything. If you use the program [TRUSS](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=truss&sektion=&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) with a command like `truss ./progname` you should see something like this in the output:

> obs_uname(0xffffc6f8,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0)        ERR#78 'Function not implemented'

This is because [FreeBSD 2+ doesn't support the `SYS_uname` system call](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uname&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%201.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and is now considered obsolete. FreeBSD's libc `uname` makes calls to [`SYS___sysctl`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) to populate the fields of the `utsname` structure. From the command line you can query the `nodename` using:

```
sysctl kern.hostname
```

You can call `sysctl` through a system call this way:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

#define OSNAME_MAX_LEN 256
/* SYS___sysctl has the value 202 */
/* #define SYS___sysctl 202 */

int main(void)
{
    char        osname[OSNAME_MAX_LEN];
    size_t      osnamelen = sizeof(osname) - 1;
    int         name[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_HOSTNAME};
    u_int       namelen = sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0]);
    char *      old = osname;
    size_t *    oldlenp = &osnamelen;

    u_int syscallnum = SYS___sysctl;

    asm("push %[newlen]\n\t"
        "push %[new]\n\t"
        "push %[oldlenp]\n\t"
        "push %[old]\n\t"
        "push %[namelen]\n\t"
        "push %[name]\n\t"
        "push %%eax\n\t"         /* Required dummy value */
        "int $0x80\n\t"
        "add $28, %%esp"         /* 7*4=28 bytes to remove from stack */
        : "+a"(syscallnum)       /* error code also returned in syscallnum */
        : [name]"r"(name), [namelen]"r"(namelen),
          [old]"r"(old)  , [oldlenp]"r"(oldlenp),
          [new]"i"(NULL), [newlen]"i"(0)
        : "memory");

    if (syscallnum) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    osname[osnamelen]='\0';     /* Ensure the OS Name is Null terminated */
    printf("This machine's node name is %s\n", osname);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When inline assembly adjusts *ESP* (`push` etc) it can cause memory operands generated by GCC and passed via a constraint to point at the wrong memory locations. This is especially true if any of the data is placed on the stack. To avoid this problem it is easiest to pass the addresses via registers.

Using the `syscall` function rather than inline assembly it could have also been written this way:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

#define OSNAME_MAX_LEN 256
/* SYS___sysctl has the value 202 */
/* #define SYS___sysctl 202 */

int main(void)
{
    char        osname[OSNAME_MAX_LEN];
    size_t      osnamelen = sizeof(osname) - 1;
    int         name[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_HOSTNAME};
    u_int       namelen = sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0]);
    char *      old = osname;
    size_t *    oldlenp = &osnamelen;

    if (syscall(SYS___sysctl, name, namelen, old, oldlenp, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("sysctl");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    osname[osnamelen]='\0';     /* Ensure the OS Name is Null terminated */
    printf("This machine's node name is %s\n", osname);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```